# Android viewflow validation

Tags: java, android

Currently I have a few forms using this horizontal sliding view.

https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow

Is their a way to prevent the user from sliding to the next screen when the form is filled in incorrectly? e.g. disable the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change this portion of your copy of the ViewFlow

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
....
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    //Add an if / else here that validates your input. 
    //If it is incorrect don't let the rest of the code that is here do the scrolling.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just added a Boolean variable and a setter and getter:

```
...
public class ViewFlow extends AdapterView<Adapter> {
    private Boolean flagAllowScroll = false;
   //the rest of the code
    ...

public Boolean getFlagAllowScroll() {
  return flagAllowScroll;
}

public void setFlagAllowScroll(Boolean flagAllowScroll) {
  this.flagAllowScroll = flagAllowScroll;
}
```

And the put it on the onTouchEvent function

```
...
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
if (!getFlagAllowScroll())
    return false;
    //the rest of the code
...
```

And other in the onInterceptTouchEvent function

```
...
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
if (!getFlagAllowScroll())
    return false;
    //the rest of the code
...
```

And change it of this way:

```
...
//Allows changes
viewFlow.setFlagAllowScroll(true);

...

//Doesn't Allows changes
viewFlow.setFlagAllowScroll(false);

...
```

I hope this works for you =)